# How to make capistrano 3 run rake and start unicorn?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano

I have this in my `deploy.rb` but I don't know how to run this command in the deployment server:

```
rake db:production RAILS_ENV=production
```

And what I have is not working. I wait for your answers. And also if you know how to start unicorn when the deploy is complete.

```
 # Define where can Capistrano access the source repository
 # set :repo_url, 'https://github.com/myuser/myapp.git'
 set :scm, :git
 set :repo_url, 'https://github.com/myuser/myapp.git'

 # Define where to put your application code
 set :deploy_to, "/home/deployer/apps/myapp"

 set :pty, true

 set :format, :pretty

 set :rails_env, "production"

 namespace :rake do
   desc "Invoke rake task"
   task :invoke do
    run "cd #{deploy_to}/current"
    run "bundle exec rake #{ENV['task']} RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}"
  end
 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
%w[start stop restart].each do |command|
desc "#{command} unicorn server"
  task command, roles: :app, except: {no_release: true} do
    run "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application} #{command}"
  end
end
```

and regard your task:

```
task :your_task, :roles => :app do
  run "cd #{release_path}; bundle exec rake db:production RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}"
end
```